# Unable to read option names from drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying read name of selected option from marked drop downs so that based on selected name I can make code take certain actions. Problem is it doesn't allow me to read it(I am using selenium for it). Code line I have written(Available below image) throws an exception, so not sure how to tackle it.

website link : https://mcchip-dkr.com/en/chiptuning-database?fid=1f2zc6cezk&view=carselector#0

[image]

CODE LINE:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="select2-mcw_mtr-fl-container"]/div/div[1]'))
```

EXCEPTION:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="select2-mcw_mtr-fl-container"]/div/div[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00D269A3+2582947]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CBA6D1+2139857]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BB3A98+1063576]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BDFF3E+1244990]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BE013B+1245499]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C09F52+1417042]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BF8594+1344916]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C0834A+1409866]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BF8366+1344358]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BD5176+1200502]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BD6066+1204326]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00ECBE02+1675858]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F8036C+2414524]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DBBB01+560977]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DBA8D3+556323]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CC020E+2163214]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CC5078+2183288]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CC51C0+2183616]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CCEE1C+2223644]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x759EFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77947A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77947A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see this website uses dynamic XPaths, but first part of the path seems to always stay the same.

So we can do a partial search. Try this:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[contains(@id, "select2-mcw")]""").text)
```